# Making <a> active in menu when over div-element

Tags: html, scroll, hyperlink, anchor

I'm trying to make my  links active when I'm over the elements that the  scrolls to. I've tried every single line of code I've found for two days. But nothing is working. I'm using cferdinandi's `smoothscroll` script.

```
<div data-scroll-header id="menu">
    <div id="menu-content">
            <a data-scroll href="#weare">Company</a>
            <a data-scroll href="#product">Product</a>
            <a data-scroll href="#technical">Technical specifications</a>
            <a data-scroll href="#footer">Get in touch</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this "smooth-scroll" script.

```
<script>
    smoothScroll.init({
        updateURL: true,
    });
</script>
```

UPDATE (The CSS):

```
#menu {
    background-color:white;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:90px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:99999;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu {
    will-change: transform;
    transition: transform 200ms linear;
}

.headroom--pinned {
    transform: translateY(0%);
}

.headroom--unpinned {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.active {
    font-family:"Aero Bold", sans-serif;
}

#menu-logo {
    max-height:26px;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#menu-content {
    position:absolute;
    width:75%;
    height:12px;
    line-height:12px;
    bottom:0;
    left:12.5%;
    right:12.5%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    text-align:center;
}

#menu-content a {
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;
    font-weight:thin;
    color:#03372B;
    color:#666666;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:"Aero Book", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#menu-content a:hover {
    color:#03372B;
    transition:0.3s;
}
```

UPDATE It's working, but it's not working :O:

[image: Before click]

[image: After click, .active is there but not being applied]

UPDATE (what fixed it):

```
#menu-content {
    position:absolute;
    width:75%;
    height:12px;
    line-height:12px;
    bottom:0;
    left:12.5%;
    right:12.5%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    text-align:center;
}

.nav {
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;
    color:#666666;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:"Aero Book", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.active {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: "Aero Bold", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the links a class of "nav" and add a callback

Here is the actual code:

```
window.onload=function() {
  smoothScroll.init({
    updateURL: true,
    callback: function(anchor, toggle) {
      console.log(anchor);
      var link=document.querySelector("a[href='"+anchor+"']");
      var links = document.querySelectorAll("#menu-content .nav");
      for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].classList.toggle('active', 0);
      }
      link.classList.toggle("active", toggle);
    }
  });
}
```

Example (had to copy in the smoothscroll code)

```js
(function (root, factory) {
 if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  define([], factory(root));
 } else if ( typeof exports === 'object' ) {
  module.exports = factory(root);
 } else {
  root.smoothScroll = factory(root);
 }
})(typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : this.window || this.global, function (root) {

 'use strict';

 //
 // Variables
 //

 var smoothScroll = {}; // Object for public APIs
 var supports = 'querySelector' in document && 'addEventListener' in root; // Feature test
 var settings, eventTimeout, fixedHeader, headerHeight, animationInterval;

 // Default settings
 var defaults = {
  selector: '[data-scroll]',
  selectorHeader: '[data-scroll-header]',
  speed: 500,
  easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
  offset: 0,
  updateURL: true,
  callback: function () {}
 };


 //
 // Methods
 //

 /**
  * Merge two or more objects. Returns a new object.
  * @private
  * @param {Boolean}  deep     If true, do a deep (or recursive) merge [optional]
  * @param {Object}   objects  The objects to merge together
  * @returns {Object}          Merged values of defaults and options
  */
 var extend = function () {

  // Variables
  var extended = {};
  var deep = false;
  var i = 0;
  var length = arguments.length;

  // Check if a deep merge
  if ( Object.prototype.toString.call( arguments[0] ) === '[object Boolean]' ) {
   deep = arguments[0];
   i++;
  }

  // Merge the object into the extended object
  var merge = function (obj) {
   for ( var prop in obj ) {
    if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( obj, prop ) ) {
     // If deep merge and property is an object, merge properties
     if ( deep && Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]' ) {
      extended[prop] = extend( true, extended[prop], obj[prop] );
     } else {
      extended[prop] = obj[prop];
     }
    }
   }
  };

  // Loop through each object and conduct a merge
  for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
   var obj = arguments[i];
   merge(obj);
  }

  return extended;

 };

 /**
  * Get the height of an element.
  * @private
  * @param  {Node} elem The element to get the height of
  * @return {Number}    The element's height in pixels
  */
 var getHeight = function ( elem ) {
  return Math.max( elem.scrollHeight, elem.offsetHeight, elem.clientHeight );
 };

 /**
  * Get the closest matching element up the DOM tree.
  * @private
  * @param  {Element} elem     Starting element
  * @param  {String}  selector Selector to match against (class, ID, data attribute, or tag)
  * @return {Boolean|Element}  Returns null if not match found
  */
 var getClosest = function ( elem, selector ) {

  // Variables
  var firstChar = selector.charAt(0);
  var supports = 'classList' in document.documentElement;
  var attribute, value;

  // If selector is a data attribute, split attribute from value
  if ( firstChar === '[' ) {
   selector = selector.substr(1, selector.length - 2);
   attribute = selector.split( '=' );

   if ( attribute.length > 1 ) {
    value = true;
    attribute[1] = attribute[1].replace( /"/g, '' ).replace( /'/g, '' );
   }
  }

  // Get closest match
  for ( ; elem && elem !== document && elem.nodeType === 1; elem = elem.parentNode ) {

   // If selector is a class
   if ( firstChar === '.' ) {
    if ( supports ) {
     if ( elem.classList.contains( selector.substr(1) ) ) {
      return elem;
     }
    } else {
     if ( new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + selector.substr(1) + '(\\s|$)').test( elem.className ) ) {
      return elem;
     }
    }
   }

   // If selector is an ID
   if ( firstChar === '#' ) {
    if ( elem.id === selector.substr(1) ) {
     return elem;
    }
   }

   // If selector is a data attribute
   if ( firstChar === '[' ) {
    if ( elem.hasAttribute( attribute[0] ) ) {
     if ( value ) {
      if ( elem.getAttribute( attribute[0] ) === attribute[1] ) {
       return elem;
      }
     } else {
      return elem;
     }
    }
   }

   // If selector is a tag
   if ( elem.tagName.toLowerCase() === selector ) {
    return elem;
   }

  }

  return null;

 };

 /**
  * Escape special characters for use with querySelector
  * @public
  * @param {String} id The anchor ID to escape
  * @author Mathias Bynens
  * @link https://github.com/mathiasbynens/CSS.escape
  */
 smoothScroll.escapeCharacters = function ( id ) {

  // Remove leading hash
  if ( id.charAt(0) === '#' ) {
   id = id.substr(1);
  }

  var string = String(id);
  var length = string.length;
  var index = -1;
  var codeUnit;
  var result = '';
  var firstCodeUnit = string.charCodeAt(0);
  while (++index < length) {
   codeUnit = string.charCodeAt(index);
   // Note: there’s no need to special-case astral symbols, surrogate
   // pairs, or lone surrogates.

   // If the character is NULL (U+0000), then throw an
   // `InvalidCharacterError` exception and terminate these steps.
   if (codeUnit === 0x0000) {
    throw new InvalidCharacterError(
     'Invalid character: the input contains U+0000.'
    );
   }

   if (
    // If the character is in the range [\1-\1F] (U+0001 to U+001F) or is
    // U+007F, […]
    (codeUnit >= 0x0001 && codeUnit <= 0x001F) || codeUnit == 0x007F ||
    // If the character is the first character and is in the range [0-9]
    // (U+0030 to U+0039), […]
    (index === 0 && codeUnit >= 0x0030 && codeUnit <= 0x0039) ||
    // If the character is the second character and is in the range [0-9]
    // (U+0030 to U+0039) and the first character is a `-` (U+002D), […]
    (
     index === 1 &&
     codeUnit >= 0x0030 && codeUnit <= 0x0039 &&
     firstCodeUnit === 0x002D
    )
   ) {
    // http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#escape-a-character-as-code-point
    result += '\\' + codeUnit.toString(16) + ' ';
    continue;
   }

   // If the character is not handled by one of the above rules and is
   // greater than or equal to U+0080, is `-` (U+002D) or `_` (U+005F), or
   // is in one of the ranges [0-9] (U+0030 to U+0039), [A-Z] (U+0041 to
   // U+005A), or [a-z] (U+0061 to U+007A), […]
   if (
    codeUnit >= 0x0080 ||
    codeUnit === 0x002D ||
    codeUnit === 0x005F ||
    codeUnit >= 0x0030 && codeUnit <= 0x0039 ||
    codeUnit >= 0x0041 && codeUnit <= 0x005A ||
    codeUnit >= 0x0061 && codeUnit <= 0x007A
   ) {
    // the character itself
    result += string.charAt(index);
    continue;
   }

   // Otherwise, the escaped character.
   // http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#escape-a-character
   result += '\\' + string.charAt(index);

  }

  return '#' + result;

 };

 /**
  * Calculate the easing pattern
  * @private
  * @link https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294
  * @param {String} type Easing pattern
  * @param {Number} time Time animation should take to complete
  * @returns {Number}
  */
 var easingPattern = function ( type, time ) {
  var pattern;
  if ( type === 'easeInQuad' ) pattern = time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
  if ( type === 'easeOutQuad' ) pattern = time * (2 - time); // decelerating to zero velocity
  if ( type === 'easeInOutQuad' ) pattern = time < 0.5 ? 2 * time * time : -1 + (4 - 2 * time) * time; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
  if ( type === 'easeInCubic' ) pattern = time * time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
  if ( type === 'easeOutCubic' ) pattern = (--time) * time * time + 1; // decelerating to zero velocity
  if ( type === 'easeInOutCubic' ) pattern = time < 0.5 ? 4 * time * time * time : (time - 1) * (2 * time - 2) * (2 * time - 2) + 1; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
  if ( type === 'easeInQuart' ) pattern = time * time * time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
  if ( type === 'easeOutQuart' ) pattern = 1 - (--time) * time * time * time; // decelerating to zero velocity
  if ( type === 'easeInOutQuart' ) pattern = time < 0.5 ? 8 * time * time * time * time : 1 - 8 * (--time) * time * time * time; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
  if ( type === 'easeInQuint' ) pattern = time * time * time * time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
  if ( type === 'easeOutQuint' ) pattern = 1 + (--time) * time * time * time * time; // decelerating to zero velocity
  if ( type === 'easeInOutQuint' ) pattern = time < 0.5 ? 16 * time * time * time * time * time : 1 + 16 * (--time) * time * time * time * time; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
  return pattern || time; // no easing, no acceleration
 };

 /**
  * Calculate how far to scroll
  * @private
  * @param {Element} anchor The anchor element to scroll to
  * @param {Number} headerHeight Height of a fixed header, if any
  * @param {Number} offset Number of pixels by which to offset scroll
  * @returns {Number}
  */
 var getEndLocation = function ( anchor, headerHeight, offset ) {
  var location = 0;
  if (anchor.offsetParent) {
   do {
    location += anchor.offsetTop;
    anchor = anchor.offsetParent;
   } while (anchor);
  }
  location = Math.max(location - headerHeight - offset, 0);
  return Math.min(location, getDocumentHeight() - getViewportHeight());
 };

 /**
  * Determine the viewport's height
  * @private
  * @returns {Number}
  */
 var getViewportHeight = function() {
         return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
     };

 /**
  * Determine the document's height
  * @private
  * @returns {Number}
  */
 var getDocumentHeight = function () {
  return Math.max(
   root.document.body.scrollHeight, root.document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
   root.document.body.offsetHeight, root.document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
   root.document.body.clientHeight, root.document.documentElement.clientHeight
  );
 };

 /**
  * Convert data-options attribute into an object of key/value pairs
  * @private
  * @param {String} options Link-specific options as a data attribute string
  * @returns {Object}
  */
 var getDataOptions = function ( options ) {
  return !options || !(typeof JSON === 'object' && typeof JSON.parse === 'function') ? {} : JSON.parse( options );
 };

 /**
  * Update the URL
  * @private
  * @param {Element} anchor The element to scroll to
  * @param {Boolean} url Whether or not to update the URL history
  */
 var updateUrl = function ( anchor, url ) {
  if ( root.history.pushState && (url || url === 'true') && root.location.protocol !== 'file:' ) {
   root.history.pushState( null, null, [root.location.protocol, '//', root.location.host, root.location.pathname, root.location.search, anchor].join('') );
  }
 };

 var getHeaderHeight = function ( header ) {
  return header === null ? 0 : ( getHeight( header ) + header.offsetTop );
 };

 /**
  * Start/stop the scrolling animation
  * @public
  * @param {Element} anchor The element to scroll to
  * @param {Element} toggle The element that toggled the scroll event
  * @param {Object} options
  */
 smoothScroll.animateScroll = function ( anchor, toggle, options ) {

  // Options and overrides
  var overrides = getDataOptions( toggle ? toggle.getAttribute('data-options') : null );
  var animateSettings = extend( settings || defaults, options || {}, overrides ); // Merge user options with defaults

  // Selectors and variables
  var isNum = Object.prototype.toString.call( anchor ) === '[object Number]' ? true : false;
  var hash = smoothScroll.escapeCharacters( anchor );
  var anchorElem = isNum ? null : ( hash === '#' ? root.document.documentElement : root.document.querySelector( hash ) );
  if ( !isNum && !anchorElem ) return;
  var startLocation = root.pageYOffset; // Current location on the page
  if ( !fixedHeader ) { fixedHeader = root.document.querySelector( animateSettings.selectorHeader ); }  // Get the fixed header if not already set
  if ( !headerHeight ) { headerHeight = getHeaderHeight( fixedHeader ); } // Get the height of a fixed header if one exists and not already set
  var endLocation = isNum ? anchor : getEndLocation( anchorElem, headerHeight, parseInt(animateSettings.offset, 10) ); // Location to scroll to
  var distance = endLocation - startLocation; // distance to travel
  var documentHeight = getDocumentHeight();
  var timeLapsed = 0;
  var percentage, position;

  // Update URL
  if ( !isNum ) {
   updateUrl( anchor, animateSettings.updateURL );
  }

  /**
   * Stop the scroll animation when it reaches its target (or the bottom/top of page)
   * @private
   * @param {Number} position Current position on the page
   * @param {Number} endLocation Scroll to location
   * @param {Number} animationInterval How much to scroll on this loop
   */
  var stopAnimateScroll = function ( position, endLocation, animationInterval ) {
   var currentLocation = root.pageYOffset;
   if ( position == endLocation || currentLocation == endLocation || ( (root.innerHeight + currentLocation) >=

    documentHeight ) ) {
    clearInterval(animationInterval);

    // If scroll target is an anchor, bring it into focus
    if ( !isNum ) {
     anchorElem.focus();
     if ( document.activeElement.id !== anchorElem.id ) {
      anchorElem.setAttribute( 'tabindex', '-1' );
      anchorElem.focus();
      anchorElem.style.outline = 'none';
     }
    }
    animateSettings.callback( anchor, toggle ); // Run callbacks after animation complete
   }
  };

  /**
   * Loop scrolling animation
   * @private
   */
  var loopAnimateScroll = function () {
   timeLapsed += 16;
   percentage = ( timeLapsed / parseInt(animateSettings.speed, 10) );
   percentage = ( percentage > 1 ) ? 1 : percentage;
   position = startLocation + ( distance * easingPattern(animateSettings.easing, percentage) );
   root.scrollTo( 0, Math.floor(position) );
   stopAnimateScroll(position, endLocation, animationInterval);
  };

  /**
   * Set interval timer
   * @private
   */
  var startAnimateScroll = function () {
   clearInterval(animationInterval);
   animationInterval = setInterval(loopAnimateScroll, 16);
  };

  /**
   * Reset position to fix weird iOS bug
   * @link https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll/issues/45
   */
  if ( root.pageYOffset === 0 ) {
   root.scrollTo( 0, 0 );
  }

  // Start scrolling animation
  startAnimateScroll();

 };

 /**
  * If smooth scroll element clicked, animate scroll
  * @private
  */
 var eventHandler = function (event) {

  // Don't run if right-click or command/control + click
  if ( event.button !== 0 || event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey ) return;

  // If a smooth scroll link, animate it
  var toggle = getClosest( event.target, settings.selector );
  if ( toggle && toggle.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a' ) {

   // Check that link is an anchor and points to current page
   if ( toggle.hostname !== root.location.hostname || toggle.pathname !== root.location.pathname || !/#/.test(toggle.href) ) return;

   event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default click event
   smoothScroll.animateScroll( toggle.hash, toggle, settings); // Animate scroll

  }

 };

 /**
  * On window scroll and resize, only run events at a rate of 15fps for better performance
  * @private
  * @param  {Function} eventTimeout Timeout function
  * @param  {Object} settings
  */
 var eventThrottler = function (event) {
  if ( !eventTimeout ) {
   eventTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    eventTimeout = null; // Reset timeout
    headerHeight = getHeaderHeight( fixedHeader ); // Get the height of a fixed header if one exists
   }, 66);
  }
 };

 /**
  * Destroy the current initialization.
  * @public
  */
 smoothScroll.destroy = function () {

  // If plugin isn't already initialized, stop
  if ( !settings ) return;

  // Remove event listeners
  root.document.removeEventListener( 'click', eventHandler, false );
  root.removeEventListener( 'resize', eventThrottler, false );

  // Reset varaibles
  settings = null;
  eventTimeout = null;
  fixedHeader = null;
  headerHeight = null;
  animationInterval = null;
 };

 /**
  * Initialize Smooth Scroll
  * @public
  * @param {Object} options User settings
  */
 smoothScroll.init = function ( options ) {

  // feature test
  if ( !supports ) return;

  // Destroy any existing initializations
  smoothScroll.destroy();

  // Selectors and variables
  settings = extend( defaults, options || {} ); // Merge user options with defaults
  fixedHeader = root.document.querySelector( settings.selectorHeader ); // Get the fixed header
  headerHeight = getHeaderHeight( fixedHeader );

  // When a toggle is clicked, run the click handler
  root.document.addEventListener('click', eventHandler, false );
  if ( fixedHeader ) { root.addEventListener( 'resize', eventThrottler, false ); }

 };


 //
 // Public APIs
 //

 return smoothScroll;

});
window.onload=function() {
  smoothScroll.init({
    updateURL: true,
    callback: function(anchor, toggle) {
      console.log(anchor);
      var link=document.querySelector("a[href='"+anchor+"']");
      var links = document.querySelectorAll("#menu-content .nav");
      for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].classList.toggle('active', 0);
      }
      link.classList.toggle("active", toggle);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
a { text-decoration:none; }
.active { text-decoration:underline; font-family:"Aero Bold", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div data-scroll-header id="menu">
  <div id="menu-content">
    <a class="nav" data-scroll href="#weare">Company</a>
    <a class="nav" data-scroll href="#product">Product</a>
    <a class="nav" data-scroll href="#technical">Technical specifications</a>
    <a class="nav" data-scroll href="#footer">Get in touch</a>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="weare">We are what</div>
<div id="product">product</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!
But I'm not getting any reaction what so ever with this code.

Comment: Messages in console? Create a snippet or jsfiddle so I can test

Comment: Did you add the callback immediately after `updateURL: true,` ?

Comment: I did not at first. Noticed it after I sent you the picture. But it's still not working :( 

This is what it looks like right now.
    <script>
 smoothScroll.init({
        updateURL: true,
 callback: function ( anchor, toggle ) { 
   var links = document.querySelectorAll("#menu-content .nav");
   for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
        links[i].classList.toggle('active',0);
   }
   anchor.classList.toggle("active",toggle);
}
});
</script>

Comment: Any messages in the console? I cannot test your script since I do not have time to create fiddles and stuff. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Ok, I fixed the script - the anchor returned was not an achor but the href.

Comment: Works for me. Click the first two links and they get underlined. You do have to add `class="nav"` to the links and have divs they can go to and have `.active { something that will work on a link to show it is active }`

Comment: I added 2 pictures in my original question, check it out. It's so weird..

Comment: Please see my example. I added your font-face. Works in Chrome

Comment: Thank you very much @mplungjan !